# how to wrap few JDBC write-read statements in a transaction?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, transactions

I have few server instances which write and read from the same DB.

They run the bellow code:

this code writes a line into the DB and then updates that line.

```
//jdbc code inside
        configActivityLogService.insertLog(configActivityLog);

//jdbc code inside
        idInDb = configActivityLogService.getLatestActivityWithStatus(ActionStatus.AWAITING_COFMAN).id;
```

I saw this [post](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-transactions.htm) for creating a db transaction, but it wraps each DB command separately. How can I wrap these two lines in transaction?

Comment: You can't since you have both methods performing the JDBC code themselves. The tutorial shows in the first example how you create a transaction that spans 2 statements.

Comment: If those methods don't mess with the connection, turn off auto commit before calling them through `Connection.setAutocommit(false)`